# How to use setState when call openDrawer?

Tags: flutter, drawer

In my drawer, there are two actions, if user logined, it will show the user information, otherwise will show popup the login screen, so I want to call the setState when I open the drawer as below:

```
clickLeftMenu: (BuildContext mainContext) {
      LoginInfo.checkLogin(mainContext).then((islogin) {
        print(islogin.toString());
        if (!islogin)
          showLogin(mainContext, true);
        else{
          Scaffold.of(mainContext).openDrawer();
          setState(() {
            //I want to update the user login info for rebuild screen for show
            loginInfo = LoginInfo.getInfo();
          });
        }              
      });
    },
```

show the user info with loginInfo object in drawer:

```
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.account_circle,
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                size: setWidth(context, 8.0)),
            title: Text(
              loginInfo.name ?? '',
              //loginInfo. != null ? loginInfo.email : '',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20.0,
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              ),
            ),
            subtitle: Text(
              loginInfo.email ?? '',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 10.0,
                //color: this.primaryColor,
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

but it failed when I called that, show below error:

```
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called when widget tree was locked.
This _ModalScope<dynamic> widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is locked
```

I tried many of ways but still failed, do you have any ideas or other ways can do that?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
 Builder(
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.menu),
            onPressed: () {
              Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
            },
            tooltip: MaterialLocalizations.of(context).openAppDrawerTooltip,
          );
        },
      ),
```

Comment: sorry, can you explain how's your code work? I just use another way for solved my issue, thanks!

Comment: How to use the parameter "mainContext" directly? The context does not know that there is a Scaffold control. That's why WidgetBuilder is used, and you won't know the Scaffold control until "statelesswidget.build or state.build." is completed。

Comment: yes, so I use a GlobalKey for that, and change the async method to sync